# Improve true negative of a model

Tags: accuracy

Apart from class balancing (oversampling, undersampling, SMOTE) and hyperparameter tuning, what are other methods that can be used to enhance a True Negative of a model for unbalanced binary target variables keeping the same dataset? I have tried these methods but the TN does not improve much. I have read that models such as XGB are robust towards colinearity between variables (ex: it is safe to keep education_highschool, education_college, education_unversity) despite the variables being correlated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, adjusting the classification threshold. If you're more interested in a negative class, it seems logical to switch classes around and apply e.g. `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve` or `precision_recall_curve` to select the optimal classification threshold for the specificity/miss rate or specificity/NPV tradeoff. (Enhancing TN alone won't make any sense, of course: you can simply always predict 0 to maximize it. You need to decide on your tradeoff first.)

Comment: If i had applied under sampling/ oversampling, would adjusting the threshold be unnecessary since the classes were already balanced?

Comment: From my personal experience of optimizing for precision/recall tradeoff, the optimal threshold is often far from 0.5 even for balanced data. Overall improvement is less significant than in unbalanced case, but confusion matrix changes are plainly evident. [My recent G2Net notebook](https://github.com/dx2-66/gravitational_wave_detection/blob/main/gwnet.ipynb) has some side by side examples for a huge, perfectly balanced synthetic dataset: while the overall metrics improvement is within 1-3%, changes for individual confusion matrix cells can be drastic.